# Cannot restart nginx with configure SSL certificate on Amazon EC2

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate

I followed [this tutorial](https://knowledge.rapidssl.com/support/ssl-certificate-support/index?page=content&id=SO17664) by *rapidssl.com* how to set up their SSL certificate. I did everything according to the article, but when I try to restart `nginx`, I get following error:

```
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/etc/nginx/certs/website.co.private.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch)
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

I have in the `/etc/nginx/certs/` directory 2 files - **website.co.crt** and **website.co.private.key**.
The content of the **website.co.private.key** file is the key that is generatet from the command

```
sudo openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
```

In the **website.co.crt** file is the certificate that I received by email by `SSLRapid.com` + `Bundled CA Version (PEM)` - so basically, there are 3 blocks of certificates.

What am I missing or what could be wrong? I've create the directory `/etc/nginx/certs/` as `sudo mkdir`, I did it also in my previous project and it was working, but not in here.

It's causing me headache, I am fighting with this issue 2nd day already and no result so far. I'll be grateful for every help.

Thank you

Comment: I did and I was referred to the article I posted in the OP. The same issue still alive.

Comment: I am really curious why I got "-1" and "close" vote.

Comment: @user984621 its a configuration issue, not a coding one. Serverfault is a better place for this question.

Answer (score 3):

Check the order that you add the parts to the bundle. Getting the wrong order will cause the error you are seeing.

This is the correct order:

> cat yourdomain_com.crt PositiveSSLCA2.crt AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt >
>   yourdomain.com.pem